# How to access Plugin Variable in Plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I want to access a variable created in Plugin itself. In Craft 2, it could be simply done by `craft()->pluginName->getVar()` but I couldn't find a way in Craft 3. I have tried `Craft::$app->pluginName->getVar()` but that throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your plugin via

```
Plugin::getInstance()
```

You can then access its components defined by `setComponents`

```
Plugin::getInstance()->componentName
```

Or

```
Plugin::getInstance()->get('componentName')
```

If you just want to get properties of your main plugin class it's the same way as above. Not sure what you mean exactly by `Plugin Variable`